# Lync 2010: Capturing message that the user sends in a conversation while not suppressing the UI

Tags: c#, lync

Does anybody know how to capture the message that a sender sends the recipient in Lync using the Lync client? I know that this can be done via UI-Suppression, where I would handle both the sending and receiving but would like to do this only for specific conversation windows.

Ideally the user would be able to use Lync in normal. When a conversation is launched in my application it would get the information that the user sends to the other participant based on a specific context.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the Conversation Translator sample, it would allow you to intercept messages without suppressing the UI. There is a three part article series that walks you through the behavior of the translator:

- [Hosting Multi-Language IM Conversations in Lync 2010: Project Details (Part 1 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273001.aspx)
- [Hosting Multi-Language IM Conversations in Lync 2010: Project Details (Part 2 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273003.aspx)
- [Hosting Multi-Language IM Conversations in Lync 2010: Project Details (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273002.aspx)

While you have no need to translate the text you can capture the text that's sent according to the context rules you need.

Comment: I wanted to try and get away from extending the main window as in the translation example. Seems like that will be the only way for me to go about it though. Thanks!

Comment: I think you may be able to forgo the GUI part with a few tweaks, let me take another look.